# Node.js: shutting down Karma server kills parent process

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, karma-runner, mutation-testing

I'm involved in an OSS project that provides mutation testing for Javascript - basically testing unit test effectiveness by mutating the code that the unit test tests.

An inevitable effect of mutating code is that you may run into endless loops:

```
while(var i=0; i<10; i++){...}
```

could become

```
while(var i=0; i<10; i--){...}
```

While some basic mutations (such as this one) can be excluded it is not possible (nor IMO desirable) to exclude every mutation that could possibly cause an infinite loop.
Instead I have been focusing on detecting an infinite loop, terminating the current mutation test with a warning and continuing with the next mutation.

In Karma, however I run into a problem: a loop like the above will keep the browser occupied and send your CPU to 100%. When I try to shut down the Karma server I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: socket hang up
Process finished with exit code 3
```

This not only kills my parent process, thus leaving all remaining mutations untested, but also leaves child processes (I'm running a small pool of karma server instances) dangling which I then have to kill manually.

I've been struggling with this for quite some time now and it feels like I've hit a concrete wall. Any help is very much appreciated.

### How to reproduce?

If you want more information/context, feel free to check out the project at https://github.com/jimivdw/grunt-mutation-testing/tree/kill_looping_karma_servers

In that branch I have a file called **script_endlessLoop.js** which, when mutated, causes an infinite loop on a number of occasions. I have disabled mutations for now by adding @excludeMutations, so that needs to be removed or modified. Then running `grunt test:karma` should give you the above error. 
**Please be careful! Make sure you clean up all node related processes after running this as it could cause your computer to slow down severely**

Comment: Server instances are initiated using child_process .spawn. I think I'll try fork instead. That should start a new V8 instance and therefore spare the main process when the child's V8 runs into trouble

Comment: okay, that didn't work either :(